# Confused? How to find even numbers between two numbers? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, module, numbers

How do I find the even numbers from 6 through 16.

The thing is I'm working with events. How should I do this? I did a lot of research and found some code that might work but I'm not sure how it works. (I'm by no means advanced with vb.net - I'm just trying to finish this course.)

What I did find was that I have to use MOD? I'm not even really sure how to use that with an event? Any code would be awesome to getting me on the road to finish this assignment.

I took this code out of a program that had to find even numbers and it works great but the only downfall is that it starts from 1 and then whatever number you want it to stop at. I only need 6 through 16 ..

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module Module1
    Private Delegate Sub numManip()

    Sub Main()
        Dim evennumber As numManip
        Dim allNumbers As [Delegate]
        evennumber = New numManip(AddressOf Even)
        allNumbers = [Delegate].Combine(evennumber)
        allNumbers.DynamicInvoke()
    End Sub

    Sub Even()
        Console.Clear()
        Dim counter As Integer = 2
        Console.WriteLine("Even Numbers")
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Number you Wish to End at: ")
        Dim number As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("All Even Numbers From 6 to " & number)
        Do Until counter > number
            Console.WriteLine(counter)
            counter += 2
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Enum Numbers
        Unset
        Prime
        Composite
    End Enum
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Without diving in to the other parts of the assignment, you check for even numbers using 'Mod 2'

```
If (myNum Mod 2) = 0 Then
 'It's even!
Else 
 'It's not!
End If
```

For the Events part of it: I don't want to give you code to cut and paste, but consider this idea: your main sub iterates through the number 6..16. On each number, you raise a custom event. Inside the event you output to the console if its even.

```
  Class NumEventArgs
      Inherits EventArgs
      Public Property Num() As String

      Public Sub New(num As Integer)
         Me.Num = num
      End Sub
   End Class
   Public Event NumCheckEvent(sender As Object, e As NumEventArgs)
   Sub Main()
      AddHandler NumCheckEvent, AddressOf NumCheckEventHandler
      For i = 6 To 16 Step 2
         RaiseEvent NumCheckEvent(Nothing, New NumEventArgs(i))
      Next
   End Sub
   Sub NumCheckEventHandler(sender As Object, e As NumEventArgs)
      If e.Num Mod 2 = 0 Then
         Console.WriteLine("Even!")
      End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciated all the help that you give me and to take the time out of your day!

Answer (score 1):

This code would work great for you.. You just need to change the logic a little. This code start at 2, since counter is 2. You can of course change that number to start at whatever you want using the same logic as you enter the last number (if you can enter the last, you can of course enter the first ;) ).

The other thing you have to change, is to use the [mod operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get the remainder of the division, since when you start at an add number, you will have problem is you always assume that your first number is even...

anyway.. if you want to start at 6, just change this line

```
Dim counter As Integer = 2
```

to

```
Dim counter As Integer = 6
```

and if you always want to finish at 16 just change this

```
Console.WriteLine("Even Numbers")
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Number you Wish to End at: ")
Dim number As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
Console.Clear()
```

to this:

```
Dim number As Integer = 16
```

Comment: Thanks man this is awesome help!! i appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help me!

Comment: I have a question about the Event part do you think i can put this info in like a button click? because an event is a button click right?

Comment: A button click is *normally* handled by an event.  You can wire upevents (with or without a Windows Form) as in the second part of my example.  I would just caution trying to *equate* clicks with events; events are a much broader concept.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say you are using events?  First of all, none of the code you showed uses events, but even if your code to calculate the numbers was in an event handler, it wouldn't change anything.  If however, your code needs to raise events each time it finds an even number, or raises an event when it's done, that changes things a little.

Everything you are doing in the `Main` method is pointless.  All it accomplishes is to call the `Even` method, which you could do very simply like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Even()
End Sub
```

Even if you needed to use a delegate for some reason, which there doesn't appear to be any reason why you do, all you would have to do is something like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim evenDelegate As numManip = New numManip(AddressOf Even)
    evenDelegate.Invoke()
End Sub
```

In your `Even` method, I would use a For loop, not a Do Loop.  If you find the first even number, you could step by 2, such as

```
For i As Integer = evenStartingNumber To endingNumber Step 2
Next
```

Otherwise, you need to loop through every number (stepping by 1), and then test each number to see if it's even or odd.  Such as:

```
For i As Integer = startingNumber To endingNumber
   If IsEven(i) Then
   End If
Next
```

To determine if a number is even or odd, that's where the `Mod` operator comes in.  `Mod` returns the remainder from a division operation (the left over fraction).  So for instance,  10 divided by 4 is 2 with a remainder of 2.  When you divide any even number by 2, the remainder is always zero, so if `x Mod 2 = 0`, then x is an even number.

Comment: Guys i used the delegate on a diffrent project i just used it becaused i thought it would work all this help is helping very much thanks guys